# How to make aligned AND labelled equations (without using tag)?

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, align, labels

[image]

I have three labelled equations (as shown above) for which I would like to align (as show below).

[image]

Obviously, one way to accomplish this is by putting everything into one \begin{align} block and tagging \tag* the equations separately.

Does anyone have any suggestion as to how to do this without using tag?

Code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
    \begin{equation}
        a = a+c
    \end{equation}


    \begin{equation}
        a = a+c+d+e+f
    \end{equation}


    \begin{equation}
        a = b + c + d + e + sin(x)
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just wrap them all in a single `align` environment, and place an ampersand `&` at the beginning of each line if you want them aligned at the left side.  why do you think you have to use `\tag`?  (wouldn't hurt to read the manual for `amsmath` -- `texdoc amsmath`.)  and i don't understand why you're putting them in a figure, although i guess you have a reason.

Comment: This provides the fundamental usage of an `align` environment. You need to read up on the use of the [`amsmath` package](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need use `\tag` mandatory with `align` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{thmtools}       
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \setlength\parindent{0pt}
 \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{caption} 
 \usepackage{cleveref}

 \begin{document}
  \section{Introduction}
     \begin{align}
         a& = a+c \\
         a& = a+c+d+e+f \\
         a& = b + c + d + e + \sin(x) 
     \end{align}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, how can I use \label separately on each of the equations?

Comment: You can put label at begin of each equation or before of `\\\`

Comment: As @skpblack say, before `\\ `. For example: `a& = a+c \label{eq1} \\ `